# style tag with Thymeleaf

Tags: html, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I have this piece of code:

```
<h2 class="title"  >
                  <a th:href="${blogItem.getLink()}" th:text="${blogItem.getTitle()}"><style>h1 {color:'${blogItem.getTitleColor()}';}  Title</style></a>
              </h2>
```

but I have this error: `Mismatched property value (<color> | [initial | inherit | unset | revert])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the link styled as a header, you can surround the link with `<h1>` and use Thymeleaf's `th:style` to achieve what you want:

```
<h1><a th:href="${blogItem.getLink()}" th:text="${blogItem.getTitle()}" th:style="'color: ' + ${blogItem.getTitleColor()} + ';'">Title</a></h1>
```